# Error with "solc.loadRemoteVersion" in js

Tags: node.js, version, solidity

I am following a tutorial on setting up a pipeline to compile and deploy contracts and to do that I use a js file, but the tuturial uses 0.4.17 version of solidity while the version I downloaded is the most recent one (5.something) so I searched around and found out that I need to use this function: loadRemoteVersion so I can be compatible with the tutorial. However I keep getting an error message. Also I am not sure if I have installed some of the dependencies correctly either.

I use node compile.js to run the script.

This is the code I am trying to run for the compilation of the solidity code:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8').toString();
//console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));


solc.loadRemoteVersion('v0.4.1+commit.4fc6fc2c', function(err, 
solcV04){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Oopsies");
    }

    console.log(solcV04.compile(source, 1));
});
```

This is the contract code:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor (string initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
       message = newMessage;
    }

}

'''


I should be getting a class dump but instead I am getting this:

{"errors":[{"type":"SOLCError","component":"solcjs","severity":"error","message":"Invalid import callback supplied","formattedMessage":"Error: Invalid import callback supplied"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just wasn't aware of how the versions worked very well, but now I just uninstalled solc completely and isntalled the proper version of the compiler for node.js so no need for the loadRemoteVersion function.